# How to convert hexadecimal to Binary values

Tags: php, binary, hex, byte

I have a value like this

```
FFF7BBFF
```

The binary representation of this value is

1111 1111 1111 0111 1011 1011 1111 1111

How can I convert this `FFF7BBFF` to binary in PHP? I cannot be able to find a formula for this online?

I have tried this

```
echo $string =  hex2bin("FFF7BBFF");
```

But its not working. It shows this

[image]

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base_convert is the function to use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php

```
$hexadecimal="FFF7BBFF";

echo base_convert($hexadecimal, 16, 2);
```

output:

```
11111111111101111011101111111111
```

and if you really wanted that format ..

```
$new=base_convert($hexadecimal, 16, 2);
$split = str_split($new, 4);
echo implode(' ', $split);
```

output:

```
1111 1111 1111 0111 1011 1011 1111 1111
```